# php return last row with truncate (sbstr)

Tags: php, truncate

I've got just a quick problem. I've got code that returns the last post for separate titles for a forum. I want to limit the number of characters shown and put the (... …).

I'm having difficulty with a nested if statement in my while loop:

```
    $query  = "SELECT comment FROM Assembly WHERE title = 'Checkered' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($message))
{

 if(strlen($message) > 10)
  {
   echo substr($message, 0, 10)."&#133;";
  }
 else
  {
    echo    "Last Post:<br>";
    echo    strip_tags("{$row['comment']}");

  }
}
```

thanks in advance :)

**edit
yes css text-overflow:ellipsis; works great!! Thanks guys

***edit working code incase you want

```
   $query  = "SELECT comment FROM Assembly WHERE title = 'Checkered' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

 $comment = strip_tags($row['comment']);
 if(strlen($comment) > 30)
  {
   echo substr($comment, 0, 30)."...";
  }
 else
  {
    echo    "Last Post:<br>";
    echo    $comment;

  }
}
```

Comment: what kind of difficulty do you encounter here?

Comment: you can use css text-overflow:ellipsis and make some fancy effect/popups to view full text without using ajax

Comment: **Ten charac** `<-` That's 10 characters if you leave only alphanumeric characters in the string. Kinda short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give nout over as to the problem but I am going to go out on a limb and guess the problem. Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($message))
{

 $comment = strip_tags($row['comment']);
 if(strlen($coment) > 10)
  {
   echo substr($comment, 0, 10)."...";
  }
 else
  {
    echo    "Last Post:<br>";
    echo    $comment;

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works!! See my fixed edit ^top in the question for working code.

Comment: @hobbywebsite - Note, there is a more appropriate way to do this: http://codepad.org/IfUt3QWK Note, I won't swear on anything that regex is perfect for removing markup, but it looks reasonable.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Or if you wanna just nuke without parsing: `$blurb = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $blurb);`

Comment: Or whatnot something something mumble mumble. Regex. Not my specialty.

Comment: Regex wasn't the point, though, it was the rest of the method that I was being critical of. More or less. `:)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Ah my method ain't the best one for robust coding, infact it'd prolly get a d- for that but I am sure he'll be back asking for the best method and we will give it to him `:)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have with your code is that you have some badly named variables. You assign the result resource returned by `mysql_query()` to `$result`, you then try and fetch a row from a variable called `$message` (which you don't show the assignment of) and you then switch to treating `$message` as if it were a string, rather than manipulating the value in `$row`.

Regardless of that, if you just want to fetch the string from the DB and apply an ellipsis, and you don't need the full text, I would get MySQL to do the work for me:

```
SELECT IF(CHAR_LENGTH(`comment`) > 10, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`comment`, 1, 10), '...'), `comment`) AS `comment`
FROM `Assembly`
WHERE `title` = 'Checkered'
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

In PHP:

```
$query  = "
  SELECT IF(CHAR_LENGTH(`comment`) > 10, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`comment`, 1, 10), '...'), `comment`) AS `comment`
  FROM `Assembly`
  WHERE `title` = 'Checkered'
  ORDER BY `date` DESC
  LIMIT 1
";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo    "Last Post:<br>";
  echo    htmlspecialchars($row['comment']);
}
```

**EDIT**

Following @Jared's comments about the potential for broken strings displaying partial HTML tags, here is the way to do it that will avoid this:

```
$query  = "
  SELECT `comment`
  FROM `Assembly`
  WHERE `title` = 'Checkered'
  ORDER BY `date` DESC
  LIMIT 1
";
$result = mysql_query($query);
// Loop is pointless because of the LIMIT 1
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$maxlen = 10; // Max length before trim
$comment = strip_tags($row['comment']);
if (strlen($comment) > $maxlen) {
  $comment = substr($comment, 0, $maxlen).'...';
}
$comment = htmlspecialchars($comment);

echo "Last Post:<br>";
echo $comment;
```

Comment: Where does the ellipsis come in at?

Comment: @JaredFarrish In the MySQL query. **EDIT** Oh wait I forgot the `CONCAT`

Comment: I was just about to put that in a comment... `;)`

Comment: One other note... The OP seems to suggest that the `comment` field may contain markup. This might bomb without some stripping means.

Comment: @JaredFarrish `htmlspecialchars()` :-) - I switched to that since `strip_tags()` wont get half tags that may be created by chopping the string

Comment: But you've already truncated... With the markup in-tact. Possible (impossibly short anyways) result: `<h1> I IS<`

Comment: True, I just realised that myself. Maybe the MySQL ellipsis is not way then, it should be `SELECT` > `strip_tags()` > ellipsis, I will edit

Comment: I've always thought it kinda goofy there isn't a regex capability in MySQL.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I know, there is a *very* limited match but no replace, which sucks. Having said that, in this specific case it would be veering dangerously close to the dreaded "parsing HTML with regex", and we all know what happens if you suggest that here - you get burned at the stake as a witch. Even if you do know what you're doing. I have updated my example for avoiding the half tag scenario.

Comment: Yeah, that's like the third rail of the pasty white crew. Parsing, though, is somewhat different from stripping (IMO), but I suppose if you really wanted to clean it of markup, you could DOM parse it and `->text()` out.

Comment: Yes you should always use htmlspecialchars after strip_tags, I missed it out but strip_tags is easily flawed.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I know, but we still have to cater for the jQuery-phobic here, even if they will eventually be committed (to jQ or an asylum, one or the other is inevitable). I was one of those nay-sayers until not all that long ago, so I sort of understand the point of view, but at the same time I really am not sure what I ever had against it - especially being the John Resig fanboy that I am.

Comment: I was referring to PHP's DOM parsers. Although I think there is a jQuery for PHP server-side? Not sure if it offers that or not. Oh yeah, and jQuery is the great stupidifier. I... Can barely tie my shoes now that I have the ones that zip themselves up and walk for me.

Comment: @Sammaye You have to be very careful with the order in which you call things in this scenario, I have just updated my example because I got it slightly wrong. You have to `strip_tags()` first so you don't cut tags in half, then `substr()` the string you want, *then* `htmlspecialchars()`. Any deviation from that pattern leaves you in danger of displaying stuff you don't want to.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I know what you mean, which is why I make sure I keep doing things in Node.js to keep my proper JS skillz honed ;-) (plus generally it rocks for socket level programming, of which I do quite a lot)

Comment: I'm surprised the SO nag isn't nattering on about "go to chat you twits". Don't get me wrong now, I've got soooooo much better at JS since I started learning jQuery several years back. But there are definitely patterns I used to be able to hammer out easily that I now would squirm if I had to replicate. I'm "out of practice" with common core methodologies, I suppose. Especially direct DOM methodologies.

Comment: @JaredFarrish `go to chat you twits` - twits belong on the aptly named Twitter, we're on a higher plain of existence here (several levels higher). I know what you mean about DOM manipulation (it took me a long time to remember that there is no native `getElementsByClassName()` a couple of weeks ago) but at the same time it was the DOM manipulation that used to take all of my time when writing and I don't really miss it. But I highly recommend Node.js for JS play time, it rules (even if it does suck performance wise). I'm going to shut up now as we are way beyond the scope of this question :-D